# Error involving SQLite 3 prevents me from adding to database properly

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been working most of today on a function that creates a record in an sqlite table. I believe I am finally making some progress and it currently looks like this:

```
 shopping = True
          

  while shopping:

            itemToAdd = input("Please enter the ID of the item to add to the basket: ")
            basket.append(itemToAdd)
            print(basket)
            continueShop = input("Continue shopping?(y/n): ")
            if continueShop == "n":
                conn.execute("INSERT INTO Orders (UserID) VALUES (?)", (results[0][0],))
                lastID = conn.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
                conn.commit()
                counter = 0
                for items in basket:
                    createOrderItems = "INSERT INTO OrderItems (OrderID, ProductID) VALUES (?,?)"
                    conn.execute(createOrderItems, (lastID, basket[counter]))
                    counter = +1
                    conn.commit()
```

However, I am now encountering this error to do with lastID if I am reading the error correctly.

> line 107, in 
> conn.execute(createOrderItems, (lastID, basket[counter])) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

I have 2 tables that I am currently attempting to use:

Orders - contains only an orderID and userID

OrderItems- contains OrderItemsID, OrderID (which i need to be the same as the OrderID Just added) and ProductID(which needs to be taken from the list created and looped to make a record for each item in the "basket".

Comment: ah I forgot to mention that as it is less relevant to this specific question, but pretty much it is the ID from the user table of the currently logged in user

Comment: Side note: `counter = +1` isn't doing what you think it's doing. `counter` will have the value `1` on every iteration after the first one. Do you mean `counter += 1` or `counter = counter + 1`?

Comment: Side note 2: that whole loop isn't very idiomatic. If you do `for item in basket` you can refer to `item` directly. No need to maintain a counter or index into `basket` like `basket[counter]`.

Comment: ok so lastID, i found from another thread should be the lastID that was added to the DB, which I want to use to find the id of the order which I need to add to the orderItems table as a foreign key. and yes I intended for the counter to iterate through the items within basket , which is a list of IDs for products that the user creates through the shopping loop.

Comment: yeah, lastID is the newest addition, so I'm sure that would be linked to the problem, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```py
lastID = conn.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
```

[`lastID` gets bound to an `sqlite3.Cursor`](https://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3):

> To retrieve data after executing a SELECT statement, you can either treat the cursor as an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator), call the cursor’s [`fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) method to retrieve a single matching row, or call [`fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) to get a list of the matching rows.

The cursor cannot be converted automatically to the raw ID. You'll have to pull it out yourself, e.g. by doing something like

```py
row = lastID.fetchone()
row_id = row[0]
```

Then use `row_id` in your query instead of `lastID`.